# Minimum spanning tree with two edges tied

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I'd like to solve a harder version of the minimum spanning tree problem.

There are `N` vertices. Also there are `2M` edges numbered by 1, 2, .., `2M`. The graph is connected, undirected, and weighted. I'd like to choose some edges to make the graph still connected and make the total cost as small as possible. There is one restriction: an edge numbered by `2k` and an edge numbered by `2k-1` are *tied*, so both should be chosen or both should not be chosen. So, if I want to choose edge 3, I must choose edge 4 too.

So, what is the minimum total cost to make the graph connected?

My thoughts:

- Let's call two edges `2k` and `2k+1` a *edge set*.
- Let's call an edge *valid* if it merges two different components.
- Let's call an edge set *good* if both of the edges are valid.

  1. First add exactly `m` edge sets which are good in increasing order of cost. Then iterate all the edge sets in increasing order of cost, and add the set if at least one edge is valid. `m` should be iterated from 0 to `M`.
  2. Run an kruskal algorithm with some variation: The cost of an edge `e` varies.

     - If an edge set which contains `e` is *good*, the cost is: *(the cost of the edge set) / 2*.
     - Otherwise, the cost is: *(the cost of the edge set)*.
     - I cannot prove whether kruskal algorithm is correct even if the cost changes.

Sorry for the poor English, but I'd like to solve this problem. Is it NP-hard or something, or is there a good solution? :D Thanks to you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a flow problem to me, but not entirely sure about its complexity

Comment: @The Brofessor, could you please elaborate your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I speculated earlier, this problem is NP-hard. I'm not sure about inapproximability; there's a very simple 2-approximation (split each pair in half, retaining the whole cost for both halves, and run your favorite vanilla MST algorithm).

Given an algorithm for this problem, we can solve the NP-hard Hamilton cycle problem as follows.

Let G = (V, E) be the instance of Hamilton cycle. Clone all of the other vertices, denoting the clone of vi by vi'. We duplicate each edge e = {vi, vj} (making a multigraph; we can do this reduction with simple graphs at the cost of clarity), and, letting v0 be an arbitrary original vertex, we pair one copy with {v0, vi'} and the other with {v0, vj'}.

No MST can use fewer than n pairs, one to connect each cloned vertex to v0. The interesting thing is that the other halves of the pairs of a candidate with n pairs like this can be interpreted as an oriented subgraph of G where each vertex has out-degree 1 (use the index in the cloned bit as the tail). This graph connects the original vertices if and only if it's a Hamilton cycle on them.

---

There are various ways to apply integer programming. Here's a simple one and a more complicated one. First we formulate a binary variable `x_i` for each `i` that is `1` if edge pair `2i-1, 2i` is chosen. The problem template looks like

```
minimize sum_i w_i x_i (drop the w_i if the problem is unweighted)
subject to
<connectivity>
for all i, x_i in {0, 1}.
```

Of course I have left out the interesting constraints :). One way to enforce connectivity is to solve this formulation with no constraints at first, then examine the solution. If it's connected, then great -- we're done. Otherwise, find a set of vertices `S` such that there are no edges between `S` and its complement, and add a constraint

```
sum_{i such that x_i connects S with its complement} x_i >= 1
```

and repeat.

Another way is to generate constraints like this inside of the solver working on the linear relaxation of the integer program. Usually MIP libraries have a feature that allows this. The fractional problem has fractional connectivity, however, which means finding min cuts to check feasibility. I would expect this approach to be faster, but I must apologize as I don't have the energy to describe it detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but my first approach would be a search using backtracking:

1. Of all edge pairs, mark those that could be removed without disconnecting the graph.
2. Remove one of these sets and find the optimal solution for the remaining graph.
3. Put the pair back and remove the next one instead, find the best solution for that.

This works, but is slow and unelegant. It might be possible to rescue this approach though with a few adjustments that avoid unnecessary branches.

Firstly, the edge pairs that could still be removed is a set that only shrinks when going deeper. So, in the next recursion, you only need to check for those in the previous set of possibly removable edge pairs. Also, since the order in which you remove the edge pairs doesn't matter, you shouldn't consider any edge pairs that were already considered before.

Then, checking if two nodes are connected is expensive. If you cache the alternative route for an edge, you can check relatively quick whether that route still exists. If it doesn't, you have to run the expensive check, because even though that one route ceased to exist, there might still be others.

Then, some more pruning of the tree: Your set of removable edge pairs gives a lower bound to the weight that the optimal solution has. Further, any existing solution gives an upper bound to the optimal solution. If a set of removable edges doesn't even have a chance to find a better solution than the best one you had before, you can stop there and backtrack.

Lastly, be greedy. Using a regular greedy algorithm will not give you an optimal solution, but it will quickly raise the bar for any solution, making pruning more effective. Therefore, attempt to remove the edge pairs in the order of their weight loss.